# rqt/Process Monitor not showing a node

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, rqt, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Ubuntu 13.10, ROS Hydro-Desktop-Full (built from source)]

`rosnode list` shows it in a console but not the Process Monitor, even after refreshing.
The messages published by the missing node are included in the Topic Monitor.

I'm creating the node using `ros::init( argc, argv, "myNode");` in the main method of my executable.

This is strange.  Can anyone explain?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157021/rqt/process-monitor-not-showing-a-node/) by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2014-04-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2014-04-24**:
It seems that `rqt` needs to be run after the nodes are up in order have the Process Monitor show them.  When nodes are shutdown, the Process Monitor removes them as expected.  But they don't come back if the original node is created again.  This means you must quit `rqt` and run it again.

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2014-05-01**:
Is the node running on the same machine as rqt_top? It will ignore nodes running on remote machines.

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2014-05-04**:
Yes, same machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I works flawlessly for me.

You mention "even after refreshing". What do you mean by this? The process monitor should actually refresh automatically.

Which version of the `rqt_top` plugin have you installed? Run `dpkg -l | grep "hydro-rqt-top "` to check the installed version. The latest released one is currently *0.3.4-0*.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2014-05-04**:
When I run that command, I get "grep: hydro-rqt-top: No such file or directory".  Perhaps that has something to do with the fact that I've installed from source?  My RQT about shows:
rqt
rqt is a framework for graphical user interfaces. It is extensible with plugins which can be written in either Python or C++.
Please see the Wiki for more information on rqt and available plugins.
Utilized libraries:: Python 2.7.5+, rospkg 1.0.28, PyQt 4.10.3 (QtCore, QtDeclarative, QtGui, QtNetwork, QtOpenGL, QtScript, QtSvg, QtWebKit, QtXml, QtXmlPatterns, Qwt), Qt 4.8.4, SIP C++ bindings available.

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2014-05-04**:
'Even after refreshing' meaning the refresh button in the top right of the plugin.  I just ran my node now, after rqt was already running, and my node showed in the process list.  When I exited my node (ctrl-c which calls ros::shutdown() in my handler), rqt removed it from the process list.  However, when I ran it again, it didn't show up, though all the topics have appeared in the Topic Monitor.  And the Process Monitor refresh button does not make it show up.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-05-04**:
The button you use for refreshing is the "reload" button of the plugin. It closes the plugin and reopens it again. Please try to run the above command again - I fixed some spelling in it.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-05-04**:
Have you tried the same with a different node? E.g. try "rosrun rospy_tutorials talker" and check if it appears.

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2014-05-04**:
Both "dpkg -l | grep "hydro-rqt-top " and "dpkg -l | grep "hydro-rqt-top" return the prompt.
"rosrun rospy_tutorials talker" shows up in the plugin reliably, so it must be something to do with the way I'm creating/shutting down my nodes.